# Proximity 'Hit tests' from multiple arrays (Action Script 3)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sprite, hittest

I know this should be possible and Im pretty confident with my code. I have two arrays that are dynamically filled from another function. When two sprites from each array interact they should trigger a function, but at the moment they just glide right past each other.

```
public function mixGender ():void
{
    for (var gi:int = 0; gi < firstSpriteArray.length; gi++)
    {
        var sprite1 = firstSpriteArray[gi];
        for (var pi:uint = 0; pi < secondSpriteArray.length; pi++)
        {
            var sprite2:pinkSprite = secondSpriteArray[pi];
            var dist = getDistance(sprite1.x,sprite1.y,sprite2.x,sprite2.y);
            if (dist < 28)
            {
                /*and if they are within touching range calls a function.*/
                function ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There must be something obvious Im missing. Any hints?

Comment: Are you taking into consideration the Sprite dimensions or just the distance between their zero points? Are these Sprites within the same parent?

Comment: The sprites are a fixed size - hence for for a static distance between their centre points. The hierarchy is that each sprite type has its own Object Class, which parents the shared movement and hitTest class the above code is contained within

Comment: You mean the Sprites are sub-classes of another Class which contains the collision-detection code? What I've asked you is different - I mean do they share the same parent in the display objects list?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl:

```
public function mixGender():void
{
    // Method constants
    var radius:int = 28;

    // Collisions
    for each(var a:Sprite in firstSpriteArray)
    {
        for each(var b:Sprite in secondSpriteArray)
        {
            // Measure distance
            var d:Number = Point.distance(
                new Point(a.x, a.y),
                new Point(b.x, b.y)
            );

            if(d < radius)
            {
                trace('collision');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bit of testing with this code on the timeline:

```
var firstSpriteArray:Array = [new Sprite()];
var secondSpriteArray:Array = [new Sprite()];

mixGender(); // collision

firstSpriteArray[0].x = 29;
mixGender(); // nothing
```

Comment: Nope, nothing.  Dropping a trace of a and b in just before the distance measure is not tracing a result: which makes me think the function isn't even running. This is VERY confusing.

Comment: You'll need to run this function once every time a sprite from either of the arrays moves (assuming this would be in an ENTER_FRAME driven method somewhere). Aside from that (not calling the function) the only thing I can suggest is that either one or both of the arrays has no content.